# Where is an example of a monad?

Tags: monads

I recently have tried to understand what monad is.

Although I watched lots of posts and videos which explains what monad is and what category theory is, because it is too abstract I cant fully understand it. So

Can I have a useful example of monad??

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [this post](http://m50d.github.io/2013/01/16/generic-contexts.html) as an example of using the monad abstraction purely as a practical way to avoid code duplication.

(Many things are `Monad`s; what makes `Monad` useful is writing a function once (in terms of `Monad`) and then being able to reuse that same function with `Future`, `Option`, `Either`, `Writer`, `State` and so on).

Comment: Future, Option and so on,  are they kind of Monad??

Comment: Yes - or strictly speaking, there are `Monad` instances for all of them e.g. `Monad[Option]`.